# Push elements into array in perl and increment them

Tags: arrays, perl, push, increment

I want to do something like:

1. Write all IP to array `@iplist`.
2. Check if IP exists in array `%iplist2`.
3. If exists, then increment value for this ip.
4. If not exists, add this ip to list with value 1.

I tried something like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $list*3; $i+=3) {
   push(@iplist, $tablist[$i+1]); #This work ok.

   #But here I have problem.
   if (grep $_ eq $tablist[$i+1], @iplist2) {
      # Here I want to increment value of $iplist2($tablist[$i+1]). 
      # I know, that probably I need to use something like 
      # $iplist2($tablist[$i+1]) = old_value + 1, but I don't know how exactly 
      # to do it. 
   } 
   else {
      # Here I want to push to array %iplist2 ip adres and make value 1 
      # for this ip. (Something like push %iplist2, $tablist[$i+1]=>1).
   }
}
```

Or maybe somebody have other idea how to do it? I need just to have array with adres ip and some value. And if ip exists in array, just increment the value.

@edit

**Some sample:**

For example I have `127.0.0.1` and it isn't in array. So IP `127.0.0.1` will have value `1`. And we have for example IP `111.111.111.111` which is already in table and have value `4`. So I need to add + 1 for this value.

Maybe it will look better: `127.0.0.1` doesn't exists so I need to do something like: `$iplist2{127.0.0.1} = 1;` And `111.111.111.111` exists and have some value. `$iplist2{111.111.111.111} = some_value.` So I need to increment this value: `$iplist2{111.111.111.111} = some_value + 1`. And ip adress I have in `$tablist[$i+1]`

Comment: What do you mean by "increment value for this ip"? Can you provide an example?

Comment: you'd better to give a sample input and output so that we can understand what you are talking about.

Comment: Heh, that will be easier ^^ 
For example we have IP 127.0.0.1 and it isn't in array. So IP 127.0.0.1 will have value 1. And we have for example IP 111.111.111.111 which is already in table and have value 4. So I need to add + 1 for this value. Maybe it will look better:
127.0.0.1 doesn't exists so I need to do something like:
$iplist2{127.0.0.1} = 1;
And 111.111.111.111 exists and have some value.
$iplist2{111.111.111.111} = some_value
So I need to increment this value:
$iplist2{111.111.111.111} = some_value + 1.
And ip adress I have in $tablist[$i+1]

Comment: `%iplist2` is a hash, not an array. Checking for duplicate values is idiomatically done with hashes, e.g. `my @ips = grep { $iplist2{$_} } @iplist`. And to increment, you would do `$iplist2{$_}++`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for. The idea is to update the count of IP in the grep call. I showed how to generate the list of ip in the same order as they appear in the list. But you can also just use `keys %ipcounts` to retrieve the same list in an unspecified order.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Some data in a list with 3 items per ip
my @list = ('dummy', '127.0.0.1',   'dummy',
            'dummy', '192.168.0.1', 'dummy',
            'dummy', '127.0.0.1',   'dummy');

# Compute interesting indices
my @list_idx = map { 1+3*$_ } 0..($#list/3);

my %ipcounts = ();
my @iplist   = grep { !$ipcounts{$_}++ } @list[@list_idx];

print "IP LIST: \n-", join("\n-", @iplist), "\n";
print "IP COUNT:\n";
map { print "-", $_, " -> ", $ipcounts{$_}, "\n" } keys(%ipcounts);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have almost done it. Now I don't know just how to check if array with this IP already exists. Now it is something like:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $list*3; $i+=3) {
   push(@iplist, $tablist[$i+1]); #This work ok.

   #But here I have problem.
   if (grep $_ eq $tablist[$i+1], @iplist2) #I have no idea how make this if.
   {
      $iplist2{$tablist[$i+1]} += 1; 
   } 
   else {
      $iplist2{$tablist[$i+1]} = 1;
   }
}
```

I need to do some if witch checking if exists some element of $iplist2 where keyword is ip.
So I mean something like:

```
if($iplist2($some_key_word) already exists) then
#do something
else
#do something
```

Comment: You don't have to separate between incrementing a value, and creating a new value. Perl's autovivification will automatically create a value if it does not exist. E.g. `$iplist2{$tablist[$i+1]}++` will work just fine, even if the value does not exist beforehand.